# Change variable within a C# 'switch' statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, switch-statement

For a school assignment I'm supposed to create a menu kind of like an ATM.

My professor gave us this code to use:

```
string choice = null;

do
{
    Console.Write("[O]pen Account [I]nquire [D]eposit [W]ithdraw [Q]uit: ");
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
    choice = choice.ToUpper();

    switch (choice)
    {
        case "O": // open an account
        case "I": // inquire
        case "D": // deposit
        case "W": // withdraw
        default: break;
    }
} while (choice != "Q");
```

Here is what I did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string choice = null;
            string CustomerName;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Fantasy Bank");
            Console.Write("Please enter your name:");
            CustomerName = Console.ReadLine();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What can I do for you");
                Console.Write("[O]pen Account [I]nquire [D]eposit [W]ithdraw [Q]uit: ");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                choice = choice.ToUpper();

                double CurrentBalance = 0;
                switch (choice)
                { 

                    case "O": // open an account
                        Console.Write("Name of account holder:");
                        Console.WriteLine(CustomerName);
                        Console.Write("Initial Deposit:");
                        CurrentBalance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());  // i get a major error if someone types in a letter instead of a number
                        Console.Write("You have succesfully opened an account with an initial deposit of ");
                        Console.Write(CurrentBalance);
                        Console.WriteLine(" at an imaginary bank. Congratulations");
                    break;
                    case "I": // inquire
                        Console.Write(CustomerName);
                        Console.WriteLine("'s Bank Account");
                        Console.WriteLine(CurrentBalance);
                    break;
```

I did a little bit more, but the problem starts here in `case "I"`. `CustomerName` is getting replaced by what the user types, like it's supposed to be. But `CurrentBalance` does not change, and I have to set it equal to something otherwise I get an error.

I start to get the feeling that it may be impossible to change a `switch` variable inside a `switch`. I looked in my book for passing references/values, but it doesn't include `switch` in that section.
If y'all could give me a hint what I'm doing wrong or could show me what could fix my problem, that would be great. I'm not expecting code from you, just a little push in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the *placement* of your declaration of `CurrentBalance`.

Currently you have this:

```
do
{
    double CurrentBalance = 0;
    switch (choice) {
        /* the rest of your code */
    }
}
```

Should be

```
double CurrentBalance = 0;
do
{
    switch (choice) {
        /* the rest of your code */
    }
}
```

Now, the next iteration of your `do` loop does not reset `CurrentBalance` to `0`

Answer (score 1):

Every iteration of the loop you reset `CurrentBalance` to 0. Move the line `double CurrentBalance = 0;` :

```
string choice;
string CurrentName;
double CurrentBalance = 0;

// ...

do
{
    // ...
    //double CurrentBalance = 0; NOT HERE
    switch( ... )
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize all your variables before going into the loop, not *in* the loop, or else the variable is re-initialized (cleared to `0`) every iteration.

```
double CurrentBalance = 0;
// other code...
do { // ...
```

I should mention it doesn't have anything to do with changing variables within a switch. Changing variables within a switch is perfectly permissible.